# "Cannot find libSQLDBCHDB.dll" when connecting to SAP HANA with .NET

Tags: ado.net, driver, hana

We are getting the error "Cannot find libSQLDBCHDB.dll" when trying to connect with our AWS HANA instance from dotnet code.

We installed the HANA Client developer edition 64 bit on our 64 bit windows machine and also set the PATH env variable to the application install path.

[This link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/46/9de1336d6110148c9feec83dbeb4f0/content.htm?frameset=/en/46/9dc5ab6d6110149f37a7af9a9b4369/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/f3/5ec71c485e493aa20d0bd0e3bff06a/plain.htm&node_id=28) states that these errors might come but does not state how to resolve them.

Anyone else facing this issue?

Thanks,
Samar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Since Microsoft Visual Studio operates as a 32-bit application, both
>   64-bit and 32-bit versions of the SAP HANA client software must be
>   installed on 64-bit Windows to develop an application that uses the
>   data provider.

[Source](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/46/9de1336d6110148c9feec83dbeb4f0/content.htm?frameset=/en/46/9db8536d6110148e81a8891f6080b5/frameset.htm&amp)

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Had to install both versions of SAP HANA client software.